# Invert list of lists of indices

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of indices, e.g.,

```
a = [
    [2],
    [0, 1, 3, 2],
    [1],
    [0, 3]
    ]
```

I'd now like to "invert" this list: The number `0` appears at indices `1` and `3`, so:

```
b = [
    [1, 3],
    [1, 2],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 3]
    ]
```

Any hints on how to do that fast? (The lists I'm dealing with are potentially large.)

*Bonus:* I know that each index appears exactly twice in `a` (just like in the above example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code *doesn't* rely on the fact that each number appears exactly twice. It's also quite straightforward and avoids the overhead of building a dictionary and then copying the results from there:

```
a = [
        [2],
        [0, 1, 3, 2],
        [1],
        [0, 3]
    ]

b = []

for i, nums in enumerate(a):

    # For each number found at this index
    for num in nums:


        # If needed, extend b to cover the new needed range
        b += [[] for _ in range(num + 1 - len(b)]

        # Store the index
        b[num].append(i)

print(b)

# Output:
# [[1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: If space efficiency is an issue you could also remove each `num` from the inner lists as you come across them. You would have to iterate backwards though your lists though so the iteration does break as you modify the list that you are iterating over.

Comment: Could use `list.extend()` or `+=` to [skip](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38163035/244297)  the innermost loop.

Comment: @eugeney Could you give an example? Do you mean to just replace the loop with list comprehension? Or something else?

Comment: @smarx: see the example in my answer (linked in the previous comment). Using `extend()` speeds this up a lot, as Douglas's benchmark demonstrates.

Answer (score 5):

Use a dictionary to collect inverted indices into, use `enumerate()` to generate  indices for the `a` entries:

```
inverted = {}
for index, numbers in enumerate(a):
    for number in numbers:
        inverted.setdefault(number, []).append(index)

b = [inverted.get(i, []) for i in range(max(inverted) + 1)]
```

The dictionary gives you efficient random access to add inversions to, but this does mean you need to take into account indices may be missing from the inversion, hence the `range(max(inverted))` loop to make sure all indices between 0 and the maximum are covered.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [
...     [2],
...     [0, 1, 3, 2],
...     [1],
...     [0, 3]
...     ]
>>> inverted = {}
>>> for index, numbers in enumerate(a):
...     for number in numbers:
...         inverted.setdefault(number, []).append(index)
...
>>> [inverted.get(i, []) for i in range(max(inverted) + 1)]
[[1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not use `defaultdict` in this situation?

Comment: @Fawful: simplicity. `dict.setdefault()` works just as well, doesn't require an import and lets the programmer control when new keys are added.

Comment: Since @Nico specifically asked about efficiency, I want to point out that this code has the overhead of creating a new list with all the data after building up the dictionary. Depending on what's to be done with the list, it might be more efficient to just enumerate the values directly from the dictionary instead of copying them into a list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each index appears only twice, the following code works:

```
from itertools import chain

a = [[2],
     [0, 1, 3, 2],
     [1],
     [0, 3]]

b = (max(chain(*a)) + 1) * [None]

for i, lst in enumerate(a):
    for j in lst:
        if not b[j]:
            b[j] = [i, None]
        else:
            b[j][1] = i
```

As pointed out by @smarx, if we further assume that `len(a)` represents the range of values, as in the example, the above solution can be simplified to:

```
a = [[2],
     [0, 1, 3, 2],
     [1],
     [0, 3]]

b = len(a) * [[None]]

for i, lst in enumerate(a):
    for j in lst:
        if not b[j]:
            b[j] = [i, None]
        else:
            b[j][1] = i
```

EDIT:
**Comparison of solutions.**

The use of `append` is not optimal for large arrays, since it reallocates memory. Hence, looping over the array `a` twice might be faster.

In order to test it, I have created a function `gen_list`, which generates a list under the assumptions of the question. The code follows:

```
# This answer's solution
def solution1(a):
    from itertools import chain

    b = (max(chain(*a)) + 1)* [None]

    for i, lst in enumerate(a):
        for j in lst:
            if not b[j]:
                b[j] = [i, None]
            else:
                b[j][1] = i

    return b


# smarx's solution
def solution2(a):
    b = []

    for i, nums in enumerate(a):

        # For each number found at this index
        for num in nums:

            # If needed, extend b to cover the new needed range
            for _ in range(num + 1 - len(b)):
                b.append([])

            # Store the index
            b[num].append(i)

    return b


# Martijn Pieters's solution
def solution3(a):
    inverted = {}
    for index, numbers in enumerate(a):
        for number in numbers:
            inverted.setdefault(number, []).append(index)

    return [inverted.get(i, []) for i in range(max(inverted) + 1)]


# eugene y's solution
def solution4(a):
    b = []    
    for i, lst in enumerate(a):
        for j in lst:
            if j >= len(b):
                b += [[] for _ in range(j - len(b) + 1)]
            b[j].append(i)


def gen_list(n):
    from numpy.random import choice
    lst = []
    for _ in range(n):
        lst.append([])
    for i in range(n):
        lst[choice(n)].append(i)
        lst[choice(n)].append(i)
    return lst
```

Then, testing the speed of the solution yields:

```
In [1]: a = gen_list(10)

In [2]: %timeit solution1(a)
The slowest run took 8.68 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.45 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit solution2(a)
The slowest run took 4.88 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.5 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit solution3(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit solution4(a)
The slowest run took 5.69 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop

In [6]: a = gen_list(100)

In [7]: %timeit solution1(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.5 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit solution2(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop

In [9]: %timeit solution3(a)
The slowest run took 5.28 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit solution4(a)
The slowest run took 6.75 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 76.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: This code makes the assumption that `len(a)` is also the range of the values that can appear in `a`. E.g., the input `[[9, 8], [8, 9]]` would fail with an `IndexError`. I'm not sure whether this is a valid assumption?

Comment: Interesting. Can you also include [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38163035/244297)? On my machine it's actually the fastest.

Comment: @eugeney Done! It's indeed the fastest apparently.

Comment: @eugeney. Sorry, there was a typo in my code. I guess we have a draw

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty straightforward `O(n)` solution that uses lists only and also:

- doesn't rely on the fact that each index appears twice in `a`.
- doesn't make assumptions about the range of values in `a`.

```
a = [[2], [0, 1, 3, 2], [1], [0, 3]]
b = []    
for i, lst in enumerate(a):
    for j in lst:
        if j >= len(b):
            # extend b to accomodate for the new index
            b += [[] for _ in range(j - len(b) + 1)]
        b[j].append(i)
print(b)  # [[1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import itertools
b = [[] for _ in range(1 + max(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)))]
for i, lst in enumerate(a):
    for j in lst:
        if i not in b[j]:
            b[j].append(i)
```

Notice that the code above doesn't assume that the range of the values that can appear in `a` is `range(len(a))`. To avoid repeated values in the sublists of `b` I check before appending: `if i not in b[j]:`

Comment: Because @Nico specifically mentioned efficiency, I want to point out that this code requires two linear scans over all the elements (one to find the max of the range, and one to do the actual work of inverting indexes).

Comment: If we're concerned about duplicates, I think using a `set` is likely more efficient than the `if` check here, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [[2], [0, 1, 3, 2], [1], [0, 3]]
>>> b = [[] for _ in range(sum(map(len, a)) / 2)]
>>> for u, edges in enumerate(a):
        for edge in edges:
            b[edge].append(u)

>>> b
[[1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 1], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: Huh? Why the downvote? Especially so fast that I doubt you actually read this and thought it through.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as [smarx's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38162985/4451578) answer. Except this one deletes item in your original array as you go along, making the algorithm more efficient on memory (depending on how the garbage collector is implemented)

```
a = [
        [2],
        [0, 1, 3, 2],
        [1],
        [0, 3]
    ]

b = []

# iterate over list a in reverse so that we can delete item when we
# are finished with them
for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    nums = a[i]

    # For each number found at this index
    for num in nums:

        # If needed, extend b to cover the new needed range
        for _ in range(num + 1 - len(b)):
            b.append([])

        # Store the index
        b[num].append(i)

    # delete this inner list, we are done with it now
    del a[i]

print(b)

# Output:
# [[3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 0], [3, 1]]
```

Note the ordering of the inner lists is reversed.